# Html5 video is laggy in browser

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I created a website and would like to play some videos in it.

```
<video id="oldtv" width="1200" height="680" data-setup='{}'>
  <source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Src is empty because the actual link to the video is dynamically changed.

```
$("#oldtv").find("source").attr("src", "video/vid" + (index + 1) + ".mp4");
```

The problem is that the video is played (very) laggy. Nothing too bad really, but it's not supposed to happen. I can play youtube-videos and stuff without any problem.
This site won't be used online and will always run on localhost, so a slow internet connection is not the problem. When I open it in Quicktime player for example, it plays fine, not slow, no lag, nothing. But when I view it in my webbrowser it almost seems like it's being played over slow internet....
It happens in Chrome and FF (haven't tried other browsers), hardware acceleration does nothing. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the bitrate of your video & dimensions of the video being served?

Ffprobe is a tool that can tell you (if your video is online, you can test with https://ffprobe.a.video)

it could be that the video is too large, and being throttled by the network.

Doug